# Recording student questions in small class 20-30 people

Tags: microphone, sound-design, audio-recording, microphone-technique, microphone-positioning

I'm building a classroom that's set up to record in person lectures for online content. I want to capture the presenter and have an option of grabbing the audience if there's a question asked or a good crowd reaction.

The room is only 2.4 m high ceilings with plenty of options of where to mount mics, room is open, but sound treated. It's about an 8m by 6m room.

I have a multi track recorder, and set up of a pair of ntg-4 shotgun mics to capture the lecturer, and a lapel mic option as a back up.

What I am after is what kind of mic(s) would be best to capture the students? I was thinking another pair of ntgs in a cross pattern?

I'd love to hear everyone's best options.

Passing around a wireless mic or lapeling everyone is not an option. I want it all just ready and running that I hit record on the 4 track at the start of the day and forget about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll be surprised how ambient that space is if you try to mic it for speech from 6m away.

A pair of shotguns facing the audience will be fine for 'reaction' but I doubt it will be good for picking up someone speaking from the back row. This is why any pro rig has a boom op; you really want to be within a meter or so to pick up a speaker, especially one who's not used to projecting & in a far from silent room.

Answer (score 0):

There is some Adobe Ai assistant that can normalize the volume and remove background noise and make it sound like a podcast voice. This is probably much more important. This and one shotgun mic should be enough but you should test it before

Here is the link to the tool https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance